# Approval Process Related User: Approver Not Available in Related User list

Tags: approval-process

We have an opportunity approval process that I created in our Sandbox. This process allows the submitter to manually choose the approver of the opportunity. As a part of that process I was able to create an e-mail alert that is sent to the approver by selecting the recipient "Related User: Approver" from the list of available recipients under the "Related User" recipient type.

I've recreated this approval process in our production environment and the "Related User: Approver" recipient is not available (I can only see the "Related User: Last Modified By" recipient option).

Anyone have any idea why the approver is not available for selection?

Here is a picture of an e-mail alert in our sandbox:
[image: Sandbox]

Here is a picture of an e-mail alert in our production environment:
[image: Production]

Comment: please go to your user object and see if the approver field is a custom field, my hunch is that  this field was created by another developer in your org, ASAIK you do not have a out of box approver field. you can vote on this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HBSYAA4

Comment: I'm not using the approver field from the user record - the user manually chooses the approver as a part of the approval process. I've added screenshots of our sandbox and production environments. As you can see the sandbox (winter '15) has the related user: approver field and the production (also winter '15) does not. Why is there a difference?

Comment: my bad about asking you to go and check the user object, check on the opportunity object in your sandbox and you should see a custom lookup relationship field called Approver__c. The related user shows all the user lookup from the parent object this needs to be moved over to production and populated through a data load or mass update tool

Comment: That made the Related User: Approver field appear. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it! :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Related User drop down is populated based on the user lookup fields related to the parent object on which the Email Alert is being built. Check for Approver field on the oppty object and push the field to production and populate the field using data loader or a mass update tool.